# Set up jupyter in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

Im new to jupyter and vs code and im trying to run jupyter notebooks the right way with a venv

**Steps taken**

1. python extension installed
2. virtual environment created and activated (venv)
3. ipykernel ( 6.0.3) installed

When I click the Select Kernel button on the top right corner I get the following two choicesl
[image]

Shouldn't my kernel installed in venv show up as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Does it exist in the python interpreter select list? If it is not, could you add this in the `settings.json` file?

```
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "venv\\Scripts\\python.exe", //the path of the python interpreter in your virtual environment.
```